# How to convert IList of unknown type (type is known at runtime) to array?

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion

I am using reflection to copy an object of any custom class at runtime. I am using `FieldInfo` to get all the fields and then properly copy them based on their type.

Only type I can work with at the start of the copy algorithm is `System.Object` (AKA `object`).
I do a lot of type checking. So when my check method says this particular object is some simple one-dimensional array, it is array, no doubt. However I can access the type of elements in that array only at runtime.

I did successfully copied `List<type known at runtime>` like this:

```
public object Get_ListCopy(object original)
{
    Type elementType = original.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

    object copy = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    var copyIList = copy as IList;

    foreach (var item in original as IEnumerable)
        copyIList.Add(item);

    copy = copyIList;

    return copy;
}
```

Then I tried to re-write the method for simple array:

```
public object Get_ArrayCopy(object original)
{
    Type elementType = original.GetType().GetElementType();    // difference here
    Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

    object copy = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
    var copyIList = copy as IList;

    foreach (var item in original as IEnumerable)
        copyIList.Add(item);

    copy = Enumerable.Range(0, copyIList.Count).Select(i => copyIList[i]).ToArray();    // difference here

    return copy;
}
```

But that returns an exception when assigning value to field using `FieldInfo.SetValue(copyObject, convertedValue) // where convertedValue is object copy from the method above`:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32[]'.'
```

For that particular example the array looked like this:

```
public int[] Array = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

One last thing: I know how to solve this problem using generic methods and `MethodInfo ...MakeGenericMethod(...).Invoke` , I just thought it could be avoided(maybe I am wrong). Also serialization can't be used.

Comment: why not just call `ToArray` on `copyList`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere IList doesn't have ToArray method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
copy = Enumerable.Range(0, copyIList.Count)
    .Select(i => copyIList[i])
    .ToArray();
```

Is actually:

```
copy = Enumerable.Range(0, copyIList.Count)
    .Select<int, object>(i => copyIList[i])
    .ToArray<object>();
```

The compiler knows that `copyIList` is an IList. When you do `copyIList[i]`, you access [IList's indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist.item?view=netframework-4.8), which returns `object`. So the `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<object>`, and the `ToArray()` therefore generates an `object[]`.

Array has a [Clone method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone?view=netframework-4.8) which will make your life easier:

```
((Array)original).Clone();
```

Failing that, you can instantiate a new array with [`Array.CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32_).

---

For the List case, it would be easier to use List's constructor which takes another list to copy:

```
public object Get_ListCopy(object original)
{
    Type elementType = original.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

    object copy = Activator.CreateInstance(listType, new[] { original });
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Just worth noting that array itself will be deep copied but items inside that array will be shallow copied. I solved full deep copying with generic method invoke. I made another question about deep copy here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491958/how-to-deep-copy-array-items-with-unknown-type-at-runtime-without-using-makegene) if you would like to look. Btw thanks.

Comment: @sanitizedUser Yep, the same as with the code in your question