# How to deep copy array items with unknown type at runtime without using MakeGenericMethod?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

I got an System.Object (AKA object) that is simple one-dimensional array (I do a lot of checks). The element type will become known at runtime. I have to do two types of copying the array:

1) deep copy array itself but shallow copy items:
- this has answer here: [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58475741/how-to-convert-ilist-of-unknown-type-type-is-known-at-runtime-to-array/58475917#58475917)
2) deep copy array itself as well as its items:

I did it like that:

```
public object FullDeepCopy_SimpleArray(object original)
{

    Type elementType = original.GetType().GetElementType();
    return GetType()
            .GetMethod("Create_DeepCopyArray")
            .MakeGenericMethod(elementType)
            .Invoke(this, new object[] { original });
}

//used in generic invoke
public T[] Create_DeepCopyArray<T>(object original)
{
    T[] origArray = (T[])((Array)original).Clone();

    int length = origArray.Length;
    T[] copy = (T[])(Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), length));

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = (T)Create_infDeep_CopyOf(origArray[i]);    // this makes the deep copy of any item
    }

    return copy;
}
```

It works perfectly but it raises some problems:

- it's unsecure to work with, other programmers might delete the method `Create_DeepCopyArray` as it is only used in `GetMethod` code and IDE Visual Studio doesn't recognize it as used (because it's passed as string)
- Look at the number of casts in `Create_DeepCopyArray` method, I kind of think there must be a better solution

Do you have any ideas to improve this?

Comment: `.GetMethod(nameof(Create_DeepCopyArray))`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Wow. Thanks. Now it recognizes one reference.

Comment: Can you provide us the `Create_infDeep_CopyOf` method? Or at least its defintion?

Comment: @thehennyy Sorry I will not do that. It's tested and it is quite large for you to analyze. But basically it checks what algorithm is able to deep copy passed object, returns delegate to that algo (yeah, throw something at me) and runs it and returns desired copy. It also has methods to distinguish between different ranks of deep copy.

Comment: Can you provide the method signature of `Create_infDeep_CopyOf`?

Comment: @thehennyy It's `object Create_infDeep_CopyOf(object original)` but why do you need that? The code above is already working I am just looking for improvements.

Comment: How about something like that? https://dotnetfiddle.net/qEXCvY